# How do I save output data to JSON file with python?

Tags: python, json

**i got output from my compy site it save data in text file perfectly but not in JSON file**

```
def get_data_user(client, client_id) :
    client_id = str(client_id)
    print(client_id)
    outfile = open('client_id.txt', 'a')
    outfile.write("-100" + str(client_id) + "," + "100")
    outfile.close()
    
    with open('data/result/client_id.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f :
        json.dump(results, f, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
```

**I got this output in a JSON file that looks like this:**

```
[
    {
        "client_id": "1100018658"
    },

    {
        "client_id": "1675348721"
    }
]
```

**But I need to save the output in a simple format in JSON file and want to add -100 to all entries**

```
{
"client_id": [-1001100018658, -1001675348721]
}
```

Comment: Well it sounds like you need to read a JSON file, iterate over the contents to add your text, then write a new JSON file. Googling each of those component parts will get you started.

Comment: Where do you get this output from? Is it something that you produce, because it will be probably better to fix that part, instead of fixing the list of dicts you get now.

Comment: Did you forget to post the code you're having trouble with?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
import json

a = [
    {
        "client_id": "1100018658"
    },

    {
        "client_id": "1675348721"
    }
]


result = {"client_id":[]}
for val in a:
    tmp = '-100'+val['client_id']
    result['client_id'].append(int(tmp))

print(result)
```

Output:
`{'client_id': [-1001100018658, -1001675348721]}`

Comment: sounds like you can use `list` comprehension to keep it simple